# How can I record audio in Python?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there are libraries in Python for audio recording.
Ideally, I need to get a cross-platform solution, how can I record audio through Python.
Ideally, in order that in this library I can either pause with the ability to listen to the recorded fragment and remove it from the audio recording, or record several audio files and after the program work, glue it into 1 audio file.
If someone knows such a decision, I will be happy to receive help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into python-sounddevice.

https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.11/

It can record and play as well as convert your music into a numpy array if that every interested you. It is a python handler of the PortAudio which is cross-platform.

http://portaudio.com